# Why am I getting low performance using "ground truth of coefficients" for prediction?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, linear

I am trying to run a simulation in logistic regression but got trapped. Why I am only get ~71% accuracy even using ground truth of coefficients for prediction?

```
set.seed(0)
n <- 1e5
p <- 5
X <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), ncol=p)
beta <- runif(p)
y <- rbinom(n,1,prob = plogis(X %*% beta))
```

Note we can get the estimation of `beta` by using `glm`. The estimation is pretty close when data size is large.

```
> glm(y~X-1,family="binomial")$coefficients
        X1         X2         X3         X4         X5 
0.68415400 0.59206451 0.29157944 0.84165069 0.08466564 

> beta
[1] 0.68309592 0.60590097 0.30353578 0.83300563 0.07931528
```

But, here suppose we are using the ground truth `beta`.

Here is prediction using ground truth and the confusion matrix

```
table(y,plogis(X %*% beta)>0.5)
y   FALSE  TRUE
0 35499 14425
1 14456 35620
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, because a probability of 0.7 still implies a probability for the other class of 0.3. Or, put differently, because your $y$ are still *sampled* from a binomial distribution:

```
y <- rbinom(n,1,prob = plogis(X %*% beta))
```

If you don't *sample* your $y$, but *deterministically* set them depending on whether your probability exceeds 0.5,

```
y.new <- plogis(X %*% beta)>0.5
```

then you get

```
table(y.new,plogis(X %*% beta)>0.5)

y.new   FALSE  TRUE
  FALSE 49955     0
  TRUE      0 50045
```

(Which is really not overly surprising, since it's equivalent to `table(plogis(X %*% beta)>0.5,plogis(X %*% beta)>0.5)`.)

Comment: thank you very much! you answer triggered another strange [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282804/can-i-simulate-logistic-regression-without-randomness) from me, could you help me with it also?